# killing Network Manager pid for Airmon-ng (Kali Linux)

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux, synergy, aircrack-ng

I have 2 computers a desktop running Win10 and a Laptop running kali linux both connected to the same monitor. I use Synergy in order to be able to control both Laptop & Desktop with the same mouse and keyboard.  Now, I use monitor mode on my laptop's *pre-installed* wifi card!  I also have attached a usb wifi in order to have internet while the pre-installed card is in monitor mode.

When i wanna start airmon-ng wlan0 to get monitor mode, I have to kill the network manager, thus killing my internet connection from the  usb, and at last killing the synergy connection, making me incapable of controlling my laptop from the keyboard!

Is there a way making network manager to only be killed for a specific interface? In my case wlan0 and stay up for the usb-wifi's interface, in my case wlan1?